# MySQL: link is not showing in correct column using while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problem in my MySQL loop.
I am trying to make a link to active and de-active my users in database.

I tried my while loop to show all my users from db and then place a link to next them.

But the problem is that the link is not showing next to its correct user, I also tried to assign an id and username to link and that is showing correct info.

the link is showing 1 step below the correct user.

[image: Here is img]

Here is my code.

```
    require('./connect.php');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($numrows > 0) {
        echo '<table class="table" border="1">
        <tr style="background-color: #0DF; color: #222; font-weight:bold;">
            <td>ID:</td>
            <td>User Name:</td>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td>Last Name:</td>
            <td>Domain:</td>
            <td>Country:</td>
            <td>Phone:</td>
            <td>Plan:</td>
            <td>Duration:</td>
            <td>Payable:</td>
            <td>Paid Date:</td>
            <td>Active Plan:</td>
            <td>Active:</td>
            <td>Register Date:</td>
        </tr>';
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
            $dbid = $row['id'];
            $dbuser = $row['username'];
            $dbemail = $row['email'];
            $dbfname = $row['first_name'];
            $dblname = $row['last_name'];
            $dbdomain = $row['domain'];
            $dbcountry = $row['country'];
            $dbphone = $row['phone'];
            $dbplan = $row['plan'];
            $dbduration = $row['duration'];
            $dbpayable = $row['payable'];
            $dbpaid_date = $row['paid_date'];
            $dbactive_plan = $row['active_plan'];
            $dbactive = $row['active'];
            $dbdate = $row['date'];
            echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$dbid.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbuser.' <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/admin.php?id='.$dbid.'">Delete</a></td>
                <td>'.$dbemail.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbfname.'</td>
                <td>'.$dblname.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbdomain.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbcountry.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbphone.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbplan.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbduration.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbpayable.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbpaid_date.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbactive_plan.' '.$changeStatus.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbactive.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbdate.'</td>
            </tr>';

            if ( $dbactive_plan == 0) {
                $status = "Activate";
                $changeStatus = '<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/admin.php?status=1&user='.$dbuser.'">'.$status.'</a>';
            }
            else {
                $status = "Deactivate";
                $changeStatus = '<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/admin.php?status=0&user='.$dbuser.'">'.$status.'</a>';
            }
        }//while loop
        echo '</table>';
```

Comment: You should have your if/else statement before the echo statement, at the top of the while loop.

Comment: You should probably move your if statement above your echo.  They way it is written right now you'd be off by one from the start, so your first row would not have a link, second would be for first, etc.  Try that and see if it fixed the issue.

Comment: thats working :D. many thanks to help. this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require('./connect.php');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($numrows > 0) {
        echo '<table class="table" border="1">
        <tr style="background-color: #0DF; color: #222; font-weight:bold;">
            <td>ID:</td>
            <td>User Name:</td>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td>Last Name:</td>
            <td>Domain:</td>
            <td>Country:</td>
            <td>Phone:</td>
            <td>Plan:</td>
            <td>Duration:</td>
            <td>Payable:</td>
            <td>Paid Date:</td>
            <td>Active Plan:</td>
            <td>Active:</td>
            <td>Register Date:</td>
        </tr>';
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
            $dbid = $row['id'];
            $dbuser = $row['username'];
            $dbemail = $row['email'];
            $dbfname = $row['first_name'];
            $dblname = $row['last_name'];
            $dbdomain = $row['domain'];
            $dbcountry = $row['country'];
            $dbphone = $row['phone'];
            $dbplan = $row['plan'];
            $dbduration = $row['duration'];
            $dbpayable = $row['payable'];
            $dbpaid_date = $row['paid_date'];
            $dbactive_plan = $row['active_plan'];
            $dbactive = $row['active'];
            $dbdate = $row['date'];
            if ( $dbactive_plan == 0) {
                $status = "Activate";
                $changeStatus = '<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/admin.php?status=1&user='.$dbuser.'">'.$status.'</a>';
            }
            else {
                $status = "Deactivate";
                $changeStatus = '<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/admin.php?status=0&user='.$dbuser.'">'.$status.'</a>';
            }
            echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$dbid.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbuser.' <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/admin.php?id='.$dbid.'">Delete</a></td>
                <td>'.$dbemail.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbfname.'</td>
                <td>'.$dblname.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbdomain.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbcountry.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbphone.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbplan.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbduration.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbpayable.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbpaid_date.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbactive_plan.' '.$changeStatus.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbactive.'</td>
                <td>'.$dbdate.'</td>
            </tr>';
        }//while loop
        echo '</table>';
```